# Can the Lorentz force cancel the centrifugal force in a non-inertial reference frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, centrifugal-force

Can a Lorentz force cancel a centrifugal force (same value, opposite vector) in a non-inertial reference frame?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

This is the [Lorentz force](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html)

[image: loreforc]

The way high energy physics experiments measure the momenta of charged particles is by using strong magnetic fields and the equality of the centrifugal to the Lorenz force in the plane perpendicular to the magnetic field.

[Here is an example of a pion decay](https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm)  to muon electron in the 2m cern hydrogen bubble chamber.

[image: pimue]

The curvature is created by   the balance of th  lorentz force  to the centrifugal,

$Bqv=mv^2/r%$

which has to be corrected by energy loss through the medium and the angle to the magnetic field.

These momentum  measurements give an accurate within errors momentum for the particles, checked by the kinetic constraint equations of the main  interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. The non-inertial reference frame just needs to rotate at the same frequency as the [cyclotron frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron_resonance).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it can. you can make a system with that property. If I want to do it I would use magnetic force to cancel the centrifugal force not the electric force.

Comment: This does not answer the question.